# Passing null value when pass parameter using action function..Please help

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:actionFunction name="hitMe" action="{!iWantMyJSValues}">
 <apex:param name="one" value="" assignTo="{!valueOne}" />
//passsing null value here
 </apex:actionFunction>

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#stars-green").rating('create',{coloron:'green',onClick:function(){
    var ratings =  this.attr('data-rating');
     alert('ratings is ' + ratings);  // getting correct value in ratings
     hitMe(ratings);
     alert('function is ' +hitMe); 
     }
     });   
});

  <div id="stars-green" data-rating="4"></div>

 public PageReference iWantMyJSValues() {
        valueOne = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('one');  // getting null value here
       system.debug('******************valueOne******************'+valueOne); 
        return null;

 }
```

Comment: Can you try in your method just debug valueOne? without assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how apex:param is used in the [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) documentation. The apex:param can set a property on the controller and is not related to the ApexPages parameters.

So code more like this should work:

```
public String valueOne {get; set;}

public PageReference iWantMyJSValues() {
    system.debug('******************valueOne******************'+valueOne); 
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `rerender attribute` with apex:actionfunction. If you don't use rerender then the actionfunction will pass null always.

Rerender is the key here. Also check @Keith's answer for more understanding of `apex:actionfunction`.

Also you don't need to use `Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('one');` you will get value without this.